# Can you install UEFI?

Tags: bios, uefi, flashing

From what I've read the UEFI replaces the BIOS. BIOSs can be flashed though, so is it possible to install UEFI on a computer using a BIOS?

If it's possible, how to do it? I'm guessing this'd be different for every motherboard?

Comment: You can't install UEFI your hardware either already has it or it has a BIOS.

Comment: Why are people downvoting the question?

Comment: @Ramhound You can put that up as an answer.

Comment: @Slowki Good call, didn't really think of searching for 'update'. Marked it as a duplicate as well.

Comment: I am not going to post an answer to a question that already exists.  Downvotes are issued by unhelpful and unresearched question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UEFI/EFI is a standard interface that acts as an additional "middleman" providing advantages that old BIOS didn't, such as booting larger storage devices.

You can't simply "install UEFI" like you're installing a new application because it must be flashed in the firmware that comes on your motherboard, or must be supported by the firmware itself. Old BIOS like PhoenixBIOS and American MegaTrend do not support EFI/UEFI straight off the bat and, thus, you must switch the firmware (or possibly update if the firmware can handle it) that does support the interface standard both to the software (i.e. Windows 7/OS X booting) and the hardware (being memory-mapped/hardwired and capable of working on your circuit board).

The ability to "update/switch" depends on the size of the firmware. Larger EEPROM (electronically eraseable, programmable, read-only memory) would be necessary in older BIOS since they ship with a limited, small amount of instructions on them(and the standard for EFI/UEFI requires more instructions that, as mentioned, provide additional features to the system).

If you're asking "is it possible to switch/update BIOS to UEFI", the answer is (roughly) yes.

Take a look at a more detailed discussion of it above(in the comments of your question).